# Expected Number of Dice Showing Same Number As Sixth One

Tags: expected-value

Source: HMMT November 2023 Guts Round Problem 8

Six standard fair six-sided dice are rolled and arranged in a row at random. Compute the expected number of dice showing the same number as the sixth die in the row.

I do not understand what the point of arranging the six dice at random in a line is. Wouldn't the problem be the same if the order was fixed to begin with and then each dice was rolled?

Comment: There's no particular meaning to the line.  It's enough to imagine that one special die is selected uniformly at random and all the others are compared to that one (note: it's not clear to me whether or not the special die should be compared to itself, though of course the two computations just differ by $1$).

Comment: Certainly.  Or even, "5 white dice and one red die are rolled.  What is the expected number of dice showing the same number as the red die?"